# Extracting a substring just after - in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a set of strings like this:

```
span-aud-result-nhd34-124
span-aud-result-jsh43-125
span-aud-result-i843-127
span-aud-result-mj43-126
```

I want to extract the ending substring after **-**

For Example like this:

```
124
125
127
126
```

The problem is that the substrings like `nhd34, jsh43, i843` are dynamic. So how can I extract the ending substring just after **-**

Thanks.

Comment: The length of the ending numbers may vary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `split()` to split the string on `-` and access last element of list:

```
x = "span-aud-result-nhd34-124"

print(x.split("-")[-1])
```

Output:

```
124
```

**Explanation:**

the `split` will return:

```
["span","aud","result","nhd34","124"]
```

`-1` refers to the last index of an array

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to find the last occurrence of the '-' character in your string and then subset your initial string based on that index:

```
>>> s = 'span-aud-result-nhd34-124span-aud-result-nhd34-124'

>>> s[(s.rfind('-') + 1):]
'124'
```